# Can't open iMacros on a 64 bit machine

Tags: vba, excel, imacros

I have a macro that works fine on 32 bit machines.  When trying to run it on a 64 bit machine, I get a error message (ActiveX component can't create object) when it hits this line of code:

```
Set iim1 = CreateObject("iMacros")
```

Up until now, all of these macros have been run on 32 bit machines.  64 machines are just begging to appear in our environment.  Any ideas or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help........

Comment: Can you manually add a reference and early bind to it?

Comment: @comintern..........can you give me an example of what you mean?  Thanks

Comment: 64-bit OS, or 64-bit Office?  If you need to run any kind of "legacy" code then you should stay with 32-bit Office.

Comment: [Here would help](http://wiki.imacros.net/Web_Scripting) regarding the references topic (early binding) browse for the path where iMacros is

Comment: ...to expand you can run 32-bit Office on a 64-bit operating system, and that's what MS recommends, unless you really need 64-bit Office for some specific reason.  If you need to work with older add-ins or libraries, then they may not be compatible with 64-bit Office.