# Why does my code throw an error "ActiveX component can't create object"

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub imacros()
Dim iim1, iret

  Set iim1 = CreateObject("imacros")
  iret = iim1.iimInit("", True)

 Dim macro
 macro = "CODE:"
 macro = macro + "'Uses a Windows script to submit several datasets to a website, e. g. for filling an online database" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "' Specify input file (if !COL variables are used, IIM automatically assume a CSV format of the input file" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "'CSV = Comma Separated Values in each line of the filE" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "TAB T=1" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\Desktop\test\test.csv" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "'Start at line 2 to skip the header in the file" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "'Increase the current position in the file with each loop " + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "' Fill web form " + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "TAB T=1" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "SET !PLAYBACKDELAY 0.2" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "URL GOTO=secured URL here" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:name CONTENT={{!COL1}}" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=TYPE:submit" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TABLE ATTR=CLASS:standardTable EXTRACT=TXT" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=""C:\Users\Desktop\test"" FILE=""test_image.csv""" + vbNewLine
 macro = macro + "" + vbNewLine

 iret = iim1.immPlay(macro)

End Sub
```

Above is the code that im using.
Could someone please let me know if there is something wrong with that and the reason for error?
* Converted the code from imacros using iMacros Scripting Code Creator to VBS string

Comment: Are you running on MS Office 64-bit version, or at least Windows x64?

Comment: Im using MS office 2013 32-bit

Comment: Are you running on Windows x64?

Comment: yes. running on windows x64

Comment: Is this VBScript or VBA?

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41250473/2165759).

Comment: It's VBS....how can I convert that to Excel VBA??

Comment: @omegastripes - I will check that question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This line might have wrong quotation marks:

```
macro = macro + "URL GOTO="secured URL here" + vbNewLine
```

You can see it here, as the next line is marked as a string:

```
macro = macro + "URL GOTO="secured URL here" + vbNewLine
macro = macro + "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=NAME:name CONTENT={{!COL1}}" + vbNewLine
```

Remove the quotation mark after the equal sign and try again.

Comment: still facing the same problem after removing the quotation mark.

Comment: Edit your code accordingly to your current changes so we can check it

Comment: done..im still using the same code as above with out the quotation marks next to the URL and removed the total rows text from dim

Comment: You removed two quotation marks, when you should only remove one. Update and try again.

Comment: Done...still facing the same problem

Comment: Looks better now. Your post is still missing some information: What are you trying to do with this error? What line does throw the code? Do you nderstand each line of your code? Update your question accordingly.

Comment: ActiveX error is in line 3 "Set iim1 = CreateObject("imacros")".  I am trying to copy a table from a web page and paste it in excel.